# Unity AudioClip Null Error C#

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to play a sound on death, but keep getting a null error. I know it is something in my code, and I have already tried looking at [an alternate question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/123743/how-to-use-resources-load-with-an-audioclip-in-unity).

This is my code:

```
public class BallHealth : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float maxPositionY = -10.0f;

    void Update () 
    {
        float positionBallY = transform.position.y;

        if (positionBallY <= maxPositionY)
        {
            StartCoroutine (RestartLevel ());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator RestartLevel()
    {
        AudioSource audio = new AudioSource ();

        audio.clip = (AudioClip)Resources.Load("GameOver") as AudioClip;
        audio.Play();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(audio.clip.length);
        Debug.Log("You Died....");
        SceneManager.LoadScene("LevelOne");
    }
}
```

I already locate my file, in the resource folder.

[image: Project structure]

How do I fix the null error?

Comment: Can you be specific about what variable is null? It would be helpful if you posted the whole error from the Unity Log.

Comment: @honeybunch My problem was that the game object don't have a audio source attached , once I create and attach it to the game object I solve the problem, thanks to bmac help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't allocate components without attaching them to a GameObject (with `gameObject.AddComponent`). Unity will return a "null" object if you try to call a component constructor directly.

You should replace this line:

```
AudioSource audio = new AudioSource ();
```

With something like this:

```
AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
if (audio == null) audio = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
```

Which will use the existing AudioSource component on the object if you already made one, and will create and attach a new one if not.

Unrelatedly, you are unnecessarily casting the same object twice here (with `(AudioClip)` and `as AudioClip`):

```
audio.clip = (AudioClip)Resources.Load("GameOver") as AudioClip;
```

You only need one or the other, or even better:

```
audio.clip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("GameOver");
```

Comment: Thanks, that solve my problem, at least at script, but still not hearing the sound.

Comment: You can also use the static method AudioSource.PlayOneShot or PlayClipAtPoint to fire off one-off cues without explicitly creating an AudioSource instance first. This gives less control over the falloff settings than creating a custom AudioSource, but is often "good enough" for simple cues.

Comment: Yeah, i manage to reproduce the sound by using the method PlayOneShot, Thank you.